# Ember: error while i am running ember serve

Tags: npm, ember.js

I am try to upgrade exisiting ember project cli version by following this tutorial

https://emberigniter.com/update-latest-ember-data-cli/

after finishing this i try to run `ember serve` it shows error like

> missing path

i doknow what exactly it was trying to say and also i am new to ember could any one help me sort out this issue.

Comment: *only* this? Its a bit hard to tell whats happening without more information. Also maybe join the ember community discord server

Comment: Please accept the answer, which helped you best. SO questions should have an accepted answer. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update#readme) to update your ember projects. Please check it out. It avoids user-mistakes while upgrading (no manual merges, etc. ...).

Comment: Thanks i  tried this. it upgraged the version but while run `ember serve` shows   ember-cli-build.js not  found error

Comment: Is there a ember-cli-build.js in your project?

Comment: No Its not inside project

Comment: That's strange! What is your current ember version? What is your target version?

Comment: now its runned i do npm cache clean and bower cache clean then ember init

Comment: my target version 3.7.1 and my current one is 0.2.7

Comment: This upgrade will be hard. This will be like upgrading 4-5 years of framework changes. How complex is your app?

Comment: It was an old app so i m trying to upgrade newer version and it throws many code level errors..okay what about 2.10.0 is that possible ?

Comment: I would try to successfully upgrade to 1.0. If 1.0 works I would try with minor upgrades to get to 2.0. If you are on 2.10, the road to 3 should be open. How complex is your app?

Comment: Honestly I would consider to start with a fresh app and rewrite/transfer code piece by piece

Comment: Yes I think Lux's approach is better. Upgrading could be a never ending story.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to delete node_modules and run npm install again. It could a package in your package.json that ember serve can't find. Also check the releases it is not easy to upgrade from older version to the latest one, too many deprecations. Also if it si too old i suggest you to start over create again the ember app.